# Javascript/jQuery OR operator not working correctly on attr value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a little difficuilty is trying to utilise the Javascript OR operator: `||` when checking the attribute value of an input.

I've used the OR operator before in the past when utilising `.val()` and it worked. My code sample is below, which essentially checks a the value attribute of an input, it works find without the OR operator, but as soon as I add it it'll almost only work for the first one, what am I don't wrong here?

```
$(".js__question-wrap").each(function() {
          if ( $(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "No" || "no" || "NO" ) {
            $(this).closest(".js__question-wrap").find("[data-radiolabel='no']").removeClass("label-is-hidden");
          } else if ( $(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "Yes" || "yes" || "YES" ) {
            $(this).closest(".js__question-wrap").find("[data-radiolabel='yes']").removeClass("label-is-hidden");
          }
        });
```

P.S:

I have already tried adding my selector after the OR operator like so:

```
if ( $(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "No" || $(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "no" )
```

I haven't had much luck with this.

This is on a Magento 2 project.

Comment: Why in the world would you have variations in value for a radio button? You should post the HTML  because something isn't quite right.

Comment: You should rather use toUpperCase() or toLowerCase() instead of multiples OR conditions. Your condition should be like $(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value").toLowerCase() === "no"

Comment: It's for a questionnaire, the user selects either Yes or No, and saves it to the database, when the user comes back to the questionnaire, it autofills via PHP / JSON the value in the database. Quite common stuff :)

Comment: Please check what value you are getting for $(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this because when you write :

`$(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "No" || "no" || "NO"` it will be `true` anyway

1. `$(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "No"` gonna be `true` if the value `===` 'No'
2. `"no"` always true because it's a string
3. `"NO"` like the second one

You have to tell to the Javascript what he have to test here `$(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value")` forEach value !

So :

`$(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "No" || "no" || "NO"`

Become

```
$(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "No" || 
$(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "no" || 
$(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value") === "NO"
```

You can use this `jQuery` function to do it : `$.inArray()` [DOC](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

`$.inArray( $(this).find("input[type='radio']").attr("value"), ["No", "no", "NO"] ) >= 0`

Same for `else if` condition !

Comment: Awesome! This works! I did some Googling on this, it was added in jQuery >= v1.4

As a precaution, I'm thinking of wrapping this in a check to see whether the site has jQuery >= v1.4.0, the reason for this is because this code I'm building is part of a module which likely will be used on about 4 or 5 sites, so may need to put some checks in place to prevent errors.

Comment: @RyanHolton Did you said that for using `$.inArray()` method ? Because you can do it with simple Javascript thanks to `indexOf()` method, this one return a `boolean` : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/indexOf.